# Importing Data to SAS Remotely

Tags: dataset, sas

I am trying to begin a project using a version of SAS I have remote access to.  Ideally I would be able to type infile 'file_name.txt' and use the file I need.  However, the directory I am in when I start SAS up is one associated with my account on this remote server.  Hence I get the error that says essentially 'I have no idea what file you're talking about there isn't one here.'  How can I get SAS to take a file from my hard drive instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a file system that's mapped your local harddrive onto the remote server, your server can only tunnel keystrokes and graphics. This is probably a job for your sysadmin, but using applications like `scp` or `ftp` can be used to transfer `file_name.txt` from your local machine to the remote server. Alterantely, if the file is short, you can copy and paste the data in a universal format (like CSV) into a text editor in your terminal or virtual desktop.

Otherwise, SAS lives on your remote machine and is unaware of your local machine's filesystem. Which is good insofar as data privacy is concerned.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I downloaded an ftp and everything is in good order now.  Another question, if you happen to know SAS well.  What should I expect when I actually upload a file?  I'm trying to upload a text file with a bunch of columns each one giving data points for a categorical or numerical variable.  SAS reads the file but then says 'invalid data for __________' for almost every line.  Is there a straightforward way to format the columns of data so that SAS can read it?

Comment: No, there's no straightforward way to format data in SAS. :) It often takes some exploration, and much depends on the file formatting. I recommend coming to grips with PROC IMPORT and the [INFILE statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm). The examples are usually the most helpful for me.